# Android studio google sceneform tools crashing

Tags: android, android-studio, arcore, sceneform

I'm using ubuntu OS, after updating google sceneform tools to version v1.11.0 it's crashin and giving following error

```
Plugin 'google-sceneform-tools' failed to initialize and will be disabled.  Please restart Android Studio.

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/sceneform-loader-jni1941805946640546286/libloader-jni.so: /tmp/sceneform-loader-jni1941805946640546286/libloader-jni.so: undefined symbol: _ZN8filament6Engine7destroyEPKNS_12VertexBufferE
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.plugin.viewer.SceneformSFBProvider.startEngine(SceneformSFBProvider.java:129)
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.plugin.viewer.SceneformSFBProvider.initComponent(SceneformSFBProvider.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:486)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$createComponents$9(ApplicationImpl.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:582)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:532)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:405)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:391)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:217)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.lambda$initApplication$0(IdeaApplication.java:77)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:348)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

It was working fine on version v1.10.0, how to fix the issue?

Comment: which is your AS version

Comment: Android studio version - 3.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Existing version might be causing that issue. You need to uninstall the existing plugin and use the beta version from this [link](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10698-google-sceneform-tools-beta-/versions). or try the standard release version

Comment: tried above solution as well, but didn't work, still it's crashing